# Cannot Edit Light Properties

Tags: objects, light, properties

I have a situation where I cannot edit light properties on a light in my scene:

[image: Cannot Edit Light]

Does anyone know how to get the properties back?

- The light is parented to an object but removing the parent does nothing.
- Duplicating the light also resulted in no properties being displayed.
- Adding a new light to the scene also resulted in no properties being editable (as in the picture).
- Restarting Blender did not help.
- Switching between different light types did not display any properties.

I can affect the light and animate its transforms but not its strength.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple - I had set up "Workbench" to do a test render last night on the animation - and you can't affect the lights in workbench mode. Who knew?

So if this turns up for anyone - now we know.