# Light properties are not showing up

Tags: lighting, settings

I am trying to adjust a point light, but the settings have disappeared on me. I expect to see something like this:

[image: Correct settings displayed]

But instead, I am getting this:

[image]

It is the same for all four light types. What setting did I inadvertently change to make these properties not available to me, and how do I get them back?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[Cannot Edit Light Properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215582/cannot-edit-light-properties)

Your Render Engine in the Render Properties is probably set to `Workbench`. Use a different render engine and you will be able to edit the light properties.

[image: Render Engine]

[image: Light Properties]